# How to "simplify" UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePickerController to take photo, there are two steps involved, "Take photo" and "Use photo". Is there any way to override the behavior, merge these two action in one?  Say "Take and use photo".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in the current SDK to do this, you should file a [bug](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) requesting the feature. There are some published examples where people crawl around in the view hierarchy to programmatically read surfaces and trigger UI elements, but those are complex to do, can have weird visual artifacts that cause support issues, and are likely to break with firmware updates.

Comment: This is no longer accurate.  These APIs have been opened up